# show/hide on radio button checked/unchecked- knockout js

Tags: javascript, c#, html, knockout.js, coffeescript

I have 2 radio buttons, When I click on the option A, a particular div has to be shown, and when click on the option B, 1st div should be hidden and 2nd div should be shown. Below is the code.

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <input  type="radio" name="test-radio" id="test-radio-Option-A" value="true" data-bind="click: test">
                    <label for="test-radio-Option-A">Text Message</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input  type="radio" name="test-radio" id="test-radio-Option-B" value="false">
                    <label for="test-radio-Option-B">Text Message</label>
                </div>
<div style="display: none" data-bind="visible: showDiv">
                test Div
            </div>
```

Following is the script I tried:(coffee script)

```
@showPhone = ko.observable false

test: =>
    @showPhone true
```

using this if I click on the 1st radio button, I was able to see the div, but I don't know if its the right way Can someone please guide me through this?

Thanks.

Comment: You probably want to use [the checked binding](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html).

Answer (score 0):

You'll be needing the two following bindings:

- checked: to put on your radio-buttons
- visible: to put on your divs you want to display

your html will look like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <input  type="radio" name="test-radio" id="test-radio-Option-A" value="true" data-bind="checked: optionA">
                <label for="test-radio-Option-A">Text Message</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input  type="radio" name="test-radio" id="test-radio-Option-B" value="false" data-bind="checked: optionB">
                <label for="test-radio-Option-B">Text Message</label>
            </div>
<div data-bind="visible: optionA">
            test Div A
        </div>
<div data-bind="visible: optionB">
            test Div B
        </div>
```

Your viewModel will need 2 boolean observables optionA and optionB for the view to bind to in this manner